# Как мне сделать деженерики для моих методов работы со структурой

Tags: c#, generics

У меня есть структура данных:

```
public struct ConfigData
{
    public bool AlwaysOnTop;
    public string Test;
}
```

Есть какой-то такой класс:

```
internal class Config
{
    private readonly ConfigData _config = new ConfigData();

    public Config()
    {
        
    }

    public void SetValue(string key, dynamic value)
    {
        
    }
}
```

В нем я хочу типизировать для метода `SetValue` параметры `key` и `value` как допустим в тайп скрипте, чтобы редактор мне подсказывал какие я могу передать ключи, а когда я ввел ключ, он бы мне показал какой тип данных ожидается в value.

---

**Вот таким способом я бы это реализовал в TypeScript:**

```typescript
interface IConfig
{
    alwaysOnTop: boolean;
    test: string;
}

const config: IConfig =
{
    alwaysOnTop: true,
    test: ""
};

function get<TKey extends keyof IConfig>(key: TKey): IConfig[ TKey ]
{
    return config[ key ];
}

function set<TKey extends keyof IConfig>(key: TKey, value: IConfig[ TKey ]): void
{
    config[ key ] = value;
}
```

Метод (функция) get:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
И set:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Я немного по лучше подумал и думаю, что лучшим вариантом будет использовать Property с get/set. Но вопрос все же интересен.

Comment: скорее всего такого же поведения в C# просто невозможно добиться, максимум что приходит в голову, это создать кастомный roslyn анализатор, который будет подсказывать, что вы используете несуществующие свойство из класс ConfigData

Comment: @ExplodingKitten, получается вариант с Property самый лучший? Ведь мы будем иметь доступ к названиям + мы будем знать тип.

Comment: ещё попробовать использовать, что-то такое: `SetValue(x => x.AlwaysOnTop, true)`, где в первым параметром будет передаваться то что мы хотим изменить, а вторым значение, но это потребует использовать reflection, код будет дико запутанным и не совсем понятно зачем, в вашем случае скорее всего подойдет обычный свойства с фиксированными именами и типами

Comment: @ExplodingKitten, не обязательно reflection

Answer (score 2):

Прям то, что вы хотите сделать, скорей всего не получится добиться на языке C#, ибо он строго типизированный, и тут строго работают с конкретными объектами, а не с некой абстракцией. Вы можете написать свой "костыль", который будет это все обрабатывать, и задавать нужные значения, находя через рефлексию по имени нужные свойства/поля, но кода там будет довольно прилично, и будет довольно запутанный.

Как альтернатива, могу вам предложить стандартный механизм, который используется много где в самом C#, а именно установка настроен через простой `Action`:

Допустим у нас есть такой класс:

```
public class Config
{
    public string Test { get; set; }
    public bool AlwaysOnTop { get; set; }
}
```

Наша задача инициализировать его, задав настройки через метод. Пишем, например, следующее:

```
public Config InitConfig(Action<Config> options = null)
{
    var config = new Config();
    options?.Invoke(config);
    return config;
}
```

Это нам позволяет написать так:

```
var config = InitConfig();
```

и на выходе будет проинициализированный объект настроек, но мы можем еще написать так:

```
var config = InitConfig(options =>
{
    options.AlwaysOnTop = true;
    options.Test = "123";
});
```

и вот у нас уже наш класс с нужными нам настройками.
Тут как видите все очень просто, мы вызываем у `Action` метод `Invoke`, передавая в него экземпляр нужного класса, он сам своей "магией" пропишет все нужные значения в класс.

И вот понимая этот принцип, вы можете пойти дальше, например, написать метод расширения, перенеся туда этот метод, и запрашивать в нем уже проинициализированный тип, получим такое:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static Config SetConfig(this Config config, Action<Config> options = null)
    {
        options?.Invoke(config);
        return config;
    }
}
```

Ну и использование будет таким:

```
var config = new Config
{
    Test = "123"
};

config = config.SetConfig(options => options.AlwaysOnTop = true);
```

Заметьте, я методом меняю только одно значение, и за нас `Invoke` автоматически все подставит, и на выходе будет класс и со старыми значениями, и с теми, что указали через метод.

Ну а дальше уже дело фантазии, внедряйте это как ходите, подстраивайте под свои задачи. Да это не совсем то, что вы хотите, но в целом, думаю отличная замена. Удачи!

Comment: Это отличный ответ, и жаль что в C# нельзя сделать то, что я хотел. Но я реализовал через Properties (если я правильно думаю). Спасибо